# Can 2 routers connect to a single internet line

Tags: router, home-networking, modem

I am trying to isolate 2 computers from each-other so they cant communicate or attack each-other in any way. As of my research I found out that the most effective way to do that is to separate them completely to 2 different networks/routers. Although when I try that(connecting both to the phone line) they fight over which one gets connected (they kick each-other out). My question is, is there a way to connect 2 routers to 1 phone line and have them both successfully connected and isolated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use two modems on the same phone line. ADSL connection is always point-to-point, which means sharing is not possible.

You can implement your isolation with a firewall. For example, a Linux PC with three Ethernet interfaces, one connecting to outside Internet, and one for each internal network. Then you configure firewall rules so that traffic is not routed between the internal networks.